# Flask wtforms validators=[validators.DataRequired()] allows empty string and skip

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm using Flask wtforms to build a note submit function, as long as there is empty string, thre validation will fail. How can I allow empty string to be inputted ,and if it is empty string just skip ,don't save it as a note ?

code:

```
class VendorForm(FlaskForm):
    notes = fields.TextAreaField("Notes", validators=[validators.DataRequired()])
    remediate = fields.SubmitField("Send to Vendor")
```

is there something like:

```
class VendorForm(FlaskForm):
    notes = fields.TextAreaField("Notes", validators=[validators.DataRequired()],InputRequired=False)
    remediate = fields.SubmitField("Send to Vendor")
```

Any friend can help?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the difference is between what you're describing and simply having no validators for the `notes` field?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement then you need to replace DataRequired with Optional validator.